# Usar dados salvos em uma Sessão

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Modifiquei minha pergunta, pois consegui resolver o problema da sessão. Porém agora tenho outra dúvida. Eu tenho este código na Controller para capturar os dados passados por parâmetro e salvá-los na Sessão:

```
public function SetImageAndColor($client_id) {
if(isset($_GET['color']) AND isset($_GET['image'])) {
    $dados[$client_id]['image'] = $this->input->get('image');
    $dados[$client_id]['color'] = $this->input->get('color');
    $this->session->set_userdata('click2call', $dados);
  }
}
```

A url com a passagem dos parâmetros que estou utilizando para teste é essa: 
`http://localhost/crm/trunk/click2call?color=4444&image=img.jpg`.

Até aí, tudo ok. Agora passando para a View. Fiz o seguinte código para verificar se os dados ficaram salvos:

```
<?php $result = $this->session->userdata('click2call'); 
 foreach ($result as $row) {
 print_r($row);
 } ?>
```

E tive como resultado:
`Array ( [image] => img.jpg [color] => 4444 )`. Certo?

Agora eu quero saber como posso utilizar esses valores dentro da `View`. Por exemplo, eu tenho esse html padrão:

```
<header data-color="<?php echo $client->click2call_color; ?>">

<h1>
    <?php if($client->click2call_image != ''): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $client->click2call_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client->name; ?>"/>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo lang('click2call_title'); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Onde, se existir esses valores salvos na sessão: 
Color irá substituir a cor do header -> `<header data-color="<?php echo $client->click2call_color; ?>">`

e image irá substituir a imagem -> `img src="<?php echo $client->click2call_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client->name; ?>"/>`

Como posso fazer essa verificação e atribuir estes valores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua sessão retorna um array quando tiver diversos resultados:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518056/codeigniter-echo-session-multidimensional-array-variable

```
//view.php
<?php 
$sessao = $this->session-> userdata ('click2call'); 
if(!empty ($sessao){  
    echo "<header data-color=\"$sessao['client_id']['color']\">\n";
    echo "<img src=\"$sessão['client_id']['image']\" alt=\"$client->name\"/>\n";
}
else {
    echo "<header data-color=\"$client->click2call_color\">\n";
    echo "<img src=\"$client->click2call_image\" alt=\"$client->name\"/>\n";

}
```

Comment: Resolveu, valeu cara!

Comment: Ou eu poderia subscrever a variável : `<?php 
$sessao = $this->session-> userdata ('click2call'); 
if(!empty ($sessao){ $client_click2call_color = $sessao['color'];`estaria correto?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso sim!! Acostumei a usar os valores direto da sessão, mas fica a seu critério (contanto que funcione rsrsrs)

Comment: Cara, eu tô tendo um probleminha aqui. As primeiras vezes funcionou perfeitamente. Porém agora não está mais subscrevendo os valores da view. O que pode ser?

Comment: Consegui, apenas precisava travar a cor com `#` pois a outra já vinha do banco de dados tratada! Pode me dar uma ideia? Ao invés de `if(!empty ($sessao)){` que verifica se ela é vazia, teria que verificar se ela é diferente de falsa. Como faço? Valeu!

Comment: Igualmente a verificação de uma variável php: `if(!$session)`, `if($session != TRUE)` ou `if($session == FALSE)`

Comment: Obrigado! E outra, eu não consigo usar o valor diretamente. Por exemplo `$session = $this->session->userdata('click2call'); 
echo $session['color'];` Só consigo fazendo um foreach, mas não posso usa-lo...

Comment: E assim: `echo $session->color;` ??

Comment: Também não. E dando um print_r($session) o resultado é simplesmente Array.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode subscrever os valores assim:

```
$session = $this->session->userdata('click2call'); 
if($session != FALSE){
    if(isset($session['color'])) {
        $client->click2call_color = $session['color'];
    }
    if(isset($session['image'])) {
        $client->click2call_image = $session['image'];
    }
}
```